# Selectively using android maps v2 based on user phone features

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I am using Android Google maps V2 in my application.

If the user doesn't have Internet connection, I send them to an alternative activity without maps.

The problem is that my app is not supported on devices that don't have openGL2, because of manifest:

```
 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
```

If i put required element to false, the maps don't show.

Is there a way to program  this somehow during run-time? Or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to program this somehow during run-time? Or any other alternatives?

Alas, no. There is [a bug in Maps V2](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4699) that requires this element to function.

In an upcoming update, this is supposed to be fixed. At that time, you could set `android:required="false"`. Hopefully, you could then [detect if the device has OpenGL ES 2.0 at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9198354/115145) and make your choice accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Android API v2 requires an explicit `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true/>` declaration in AndroidManifest.xml so there is no way to deploy Google Maps Android API v2 services without OpenGL ES.

But, [you have to try this post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/26/developing-with-the-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-and-intellij-idea/).

Comment: ok thanks, but i dont see how can that link help me with my problem?