# Use OpenGL ES 3 on Android?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-3.0

I downloaded Android NDK r9 and compiled a sample application. I have a Galaxy Nexus smartphone with Android 4.3 upgrade.

How can I find out programmatically if OpenGL ES 3 is supported on my device?

Comment: emulator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874066/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take a look to [Is there a way to check if Android device supports openGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198293/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-device-supports-opengl-es-2-0). Also, take a look to [Basemark ES 3.0](http://www.rightware.com/benchmarking-software/basemark-es-3-0/)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the [Android OpenGLES docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#version-check).  Essentially, try to create a 3.0 `EGLContext`, and if that fails you know that 3.0 is not supported.

The page also shows an alternate approach: create a context for a lower level (1.x or 2.x) and use that to call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.  If the version string indicates that 3.x is supported, you would destroy that context and create a new one.

**Update:** this approach can be seen in [Grafika's EglCore](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/EglCore.java) class.  Follow what happens when `FLAG_TRY_GLES3` is passed to the constructor.

Comment: There should be a note about the reported string returned from that call. Some Implementations return "OpenGL ES X.X" while others return "X.X", so this too is probably vendor specific (I only encountered these 2 variations, but who knows what others there could be ?)

Comment: The OpenGL ES 2.0 and 3.0 specs require that the result of glGetString(GL_VERSION)  start with "OpenGL ES X.Y", but that can be followed by other implementation-defined stuff. Implementations that don't do that should be failing both the Khronos and Android conformance tests.

Comment: I guess (but don't really know) 1.1 context will always return version 1.1 since it's not forward-compatible. You don't have to create an ES3 context anyway, you can dynamically load and use all ES3 features in an ES2 context since ES3 is a superset of ES2.