# Does the Android emulator support OpenGL ES 3.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, opengl-es-3.0

I know that the emulator [has supported OpenGL ES 2.0 as of SDK tools 17 and Android 4.0.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html), but that was introduced back in April 2012.

Does the Android emulator support OpenGL ES 3.0, or are we still waiting on that?
If not, does any other third-party emulator/simulator (e.g. Genymotion) support OpenGL ES 3.0?

Comment: Even OpenGL ES 2.0 support is somewhat limited and buggy in emulator. But Nexus4 supports OpenGL ES 3.0. And used N4 is dirt cheap.

Comment: :) so that's a definitive "no"?

Comment: Totally acceptable answer, if you answer the question.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no support for OpenGL ES 3.X yet on Android emulators. However a lot of devices running Jelly bean and above support GLES 3.0. Some of the devices that support Open GLES 3.0 are Nexus 4,5,7,10, samsung galaxy S4,Note 3 etc.

Comment: yep, I'm developing on those devices so I realize they support it. Now I want to run some automated tests on a server that has android emulators but no physical devices. : \

Comment: vulkan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581120/how-to-create-and-run-an-example-vulkan-app-that-on-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The latest Android Emulator now supports OpenGL ES 3.0.  To use OpenGL ES 3.0, your development machine needs a host GPU graphics card that supports OpenGL 3.2 or higher on Microsoft® Windows® or Linux.

See:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html

[image: OpenGL ES 3.0 in Android Emulator]

The [`gles3jni` sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/f9f26dfce3dda37cf08a56286dd268a0e94d9da6/gles3jni) from the NDK is a good option to try it out.

If it fails with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: createContext failed: EGL_BAD_CONFIG
```

also try to run first on host:

```
echo "GLESDynamicVersion = on" >> ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini
```

as the devs are currently whitelisting supported host GPUs, and that overrides it, see also: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68496715

Comment: Hi Jamal, have you actually seen this working on your own machine?

Comment: Yes. If there is any issue let me know. You can also file a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192727 and we can take a deeper look.

Comment: Awesome! Now only Vulkan is missing :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42581120/how-to-create-and-run-an-example-vulkan-app-on-the-android-emulator

Comment: I added the ini with the setting and was expecting a drop down option in the AVD to select "GLES 3.0", but I don't see one. I have Android Studio 3.0.1 installed on Windows 10.

Comment: Note that Linux is a registered trademark just as Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Neither the Android Emulator and system images nor Genymotion currently support OpenGL ES Version 3.0.

As I write this the latest (Rev. 1) ARM and x86 system images for Android 5.1.1 (API 22) report that they support OpenGL ES Version 2.0 and not 3.0.

Similarly, Genymotion's Nexus 5 Android 5.1.0 API 22 virtual device reports only OpenGL ES Version 2.0 support.

You can use the code below to check support under future system images and emulators:

```
package com.example.opengltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OpenGLESVersionActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "OpenGLESVersionActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActivityManager activityManager =
                (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo =
                activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        String versionText = "Device Supported OpenGL ES Version = " + configurationInfo.getGlEsVersion();
        Toast.makeText(this, versionText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, versionText);
    }

}
```

Comment: is this method more reliable than using glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION)? I'm curious what the difference between the two are, since running glGetString seems to be easier.

Comment: glGetString is easier if you already have a valid OpenGL context (e.g. if you're logging from within your Renderer's onSurfaceCreated). The only benefit I see to the approach above is that it doesn't require a GLSurfaceView and Renderer to work.

Comment: The Android documentation suggests using glGetString:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#version-check

Note that, in the event setEGLContextClientVersion isn’t invoked upon the GLSurfaceView, e.g.:
    myGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2),
glGetString may return something like:
    "OpenGL ES-CM 1.1"
which could be a little misleading for our purposes. This post (though it deals with the NDK) describes the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843368/glgetstringgl-version-returns-opengl-es-cm-1-1-but-my-phone-supports-opengl

Comment: As at 2020, genymotion Google Pixel 9 (API 28) also shows OpenGL 3.0 is not supported with graphic card NVIDIA GeForce GTX 860M (OpengGL 4.6 is supported, verfied via Geeks3D GPU caps viewer)

Answer (score 4):

I found the version that the emulator supported by running `glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION)`. It appears that the emulators I tested do not support OpenGL ES 3.0 or higher, but I don't want to assume that what they are *reporting* is what they *actually* support, so I'm not making any promises that this word is final.

**On my Nexus 5**

`OpenGL ES 3.0 V@104.0 AU@ (GIT@Id3510ff6dc)`

**Android emulator using HAXM**

`OpenGL ES 2.0 (2.1 NVIDIA-10.2.7 310.41.25f01)`

**Genymotion emulator**

`OpenGL ES 2.0 (2.1 NVIDIA-10.2.7 310.41.25f01)`