# Static call to glGetString() returns null in Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

My application needs to check the availability of some OpenGL ES features before starting.

This is done with the following Java code:

```
String extensions = GLES20.glGetString( GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS );
```

And it worked on Android up to version 4.4, but now returns null, and the log says

```
10-28 17:53:49.475: E/libEGL(8930): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

How do I get this information on Android 5.0? Do I need to create a new OpenGL ES context? And what's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: You can't run GL functions before creating an OpenGL context. You most likely don't have one when static initializers run.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. It has always worked, but on Android 5.0 it doesn't anymore. Is there a way to create a "dummy" context  and call this static function?

Comment: I don't know about Android programming, but I suspect that Android sets up your context for you, and that pre-5.0 versions had set it up before initializing static vars while 5.0+ versions don't. Instead checking in a static context, check the first time you start drawing.

Comment: "Start drawing" is done by JNI functions in another activity, and the application needs this information before it happens. I am not in a static initializer context, the main activity of my application is already on the screen. Only the glGetString function is static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is probably not an upgrade issue, but a device-specific issue. Maybe (yours truly does not have enough statistical data across the thousands of device models), this kind of behavior of **glGetString()** is less likely to happen on older models, but such knowledge is not worth to seek, it doesn't help to resolve the problem anyway.

The [khronos wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Linux_and_X-Windows) explains that a live rendering GL context is required for all OpenGL functions to work, but it is not a violation for some of these functions to return non-NULL when called without such context.

You can find examples of initialization code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844358/192373) and [here](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/GlesInfoActivity.java).

Even then, we have encountered some devices that returned NULL for **glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER)**; these have different manufacturers, platform levels, etc. Our Crashlytcis data does not suggest that this behavior is consistent for the same device.

Therefore, we had to employ a fallback so that the app does not crash when this function returns **null**.