GLES20.GL_RENDERER returns null in Android
I'm developing an Android library and need to retrieve the GPU information, specifically the renderer name. I have the following code:
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class GPUInfo {
    private Context context;

    public GPUInfo(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getGLRenderer() {
        return GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER);
    }
}

However, when I call getGLRenderer(), it returns null. Apparently to get GPU information, we need to use a GLSurfaceView, but in my code I only have access to a Context object and don't have access to other things. I may also be able to get android.view.Surface as well.
Is there a way to retrieve the GPU renderer name in my case within the constraints of my code? How to achieve that?

You need to create an EGLContext. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614632/static-call-to-glgetstring-returns-null-in-android-5-0
