# Android Emulator and OpenGL ES3: EGL_BAD_CONFIG

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, kvm, opengl-es-3.0

I am running an [Android Virtual Device](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) on my Ubuntu host.
It is using the CPU/ABI Intel Atom (x86) and I am using the host GPU.
The emulator is using a [Kernel-based Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine).

[image: settings used]

This works splendidly as long as I use an OpenGL ES2 context.
If my app attempts to create an OpenGL ES3 context however, using...

```
const EGLint contextAttribs[] = {
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3,
    EGL_NONE
};
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);
```

...then I get an **EGL_BAD_CONFIG** error:

```
I/biplane ( 2839): EGL: vendor Android version 1.4 Android META-EGL
I/biplane ( 2839): EGL: client apis OpenGL_ES
I/biplane ( 2839): number of EGL configurations that match our preferred criteria: 1
I/biplane ( 2839): R8 G8 B8 A8 DEPTH24
E/EGL_emulation( 2839): tid 2852: eglCreateContext(919): error 0x3005 (EGL_BAD_CONFIG)
```

Requesting ES3 on a hardware mobile device, works well.
But when requesting it from the emulator, it fails.
The host machine is perfectly capable of doing OpenGL ES3.0, ES3.1 and ES3.2 as can be seen from glxinfo:

```
$ glxinfo | grep ES3
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect,
```

Is there a way to run OpenGL ES3 apps on an Android Virtual Device on top of kvm?

Comment: How do you choose the config? Are you using one that supports ES3?

Comment: I had pretty much the same problem and gave up after learning that the android emulator doesn't support OpenGL ES3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874066/does-the-android-emulator-support-opengl-es-3-0

Answer (score 14):

Running GLES3 apps in the emulator is supported in Android Studio 3.0 and higher.

At the time of writing, preview builds of this version are available.
See: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html

After launching the emulator, you need to change a setting, and restart the emulator as depicted below.

Also, make sure your app requests an ES3 context, because the Android sample code gles3jni does not do so.

[image]

**UPDATE jun 2018**

In the latest Android Studio, I can no longer select OpenGL ES3.1, even though it is the same PC.

[image]

To make it work, I had to add a file to ~/.android/ directory.

```
cd ~/.android/
$ echo "GLESDynamicVersion = on" >> ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini
```

Comment: Now it in "Advanced" tab

Comment: I want to upvote this 100 times! Creaing the file 'advancedFeatures.ini' with "GLESDynamicVersion = on" did the job for me. Although i can only choose OpenGL ES 2.0, the device is creating 3.1 context when requesting it!

Answer (score 2):

Notice :
[image]

OpenGL SE should be opened in emulator > Setting > Advanced

Not in the ADB page.