# Is there a way to use system OpenGL ES implementation in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, opengl-es

So, I am trying to use OpenGL ES 3.1 in my application, but Android AVD with host GPU setting only supports OpenGL ES 3.0. But my system OpenGL ES implementation supports up to 3.2. Can i use my system OpenGL ES implementation in AVD?

```
maks@maks-s-machinery:~$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL ES" 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 390.138
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer for [Android Emulator and OpenGL ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44552548/295004)?