# Why doesn't the Android Studio AVD allow me to select GLES 3.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

The Android Developers website says that the emulator in Android Studio 3.0 supports OpenGl ES 3.0 for Android Oreo system images. 
Here is the article:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html

However, I have not been able to select GLES 3.0 from the graphics selection menu. I have made sure that I updated to the latest version of the SDK, and the HAXM.

I read in another post that the computers must have a graphics driver that supports at least OpenGl 3.2. I verified that my computer's graphics card can support it. I have the latest Nvidia Drivers with OpenGl 4.6 support.

What else should I try?

I am currently developing games that require GLES 3.0 support.

[Screen shot of the AVD Manager set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OibOH.jpg)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm also having this issue...

Answer (score 2):

It's puzzling. It works without setting OpenGL ES version in AVD Manager.

Even when launching Emulator Device, it isn't necessary to set the version in the options under Settings -> Advanced -> OpenGL ES API Level.

All you need to do is to force support for your graphics card:

```
echo "GLESDynamicVersion = on" >> ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini
```

Also can check OpenGL ES version with:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
glxinfo | grep "version"
```

If your grphics card does not support at least OpenGL ES 3.2, try to use proprietary drivers. (Under Ubuntu: Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers)

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117381/5164462