# Does Android Studio Emulator support OpenGL ES 3.2?

Tags: android-studio, opengl-es, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, unreal-engine5

I am going to start mobile game development with Unreal Engine 5.1
It is required to use only devices that support GLES 3.2+. Early versions deprecated already starting from UE5.0
On my own phone, the build of my game deploys (via USB Debug) and runs correctly. But in reason that it`s too old and slow and has small storage, I want to use Android Emulator on my PC to test my game
But, if I understood correctly, AVD doesn't support it with standard methods, and it gives me only choose between GLES2.0/GLES3.1

I already trying to find information from the Unreal Engine side, and since I found that GLES3.1 and lower is deprecated, i understood that the only way to solve this- it`s Android Studio Emulator and it`s options
I already tried [answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698247/why-doesnt-the-android-studio-avd-allow-me-to-select-gles-3-0), about configuration

```
/.android/advancedFeatures.ini
```

And it's don't work for me (only give me a chance to set GLES version SW2.0/HW2.0 on device creation, not in the emulation setting)
SO, my question is:
Is it possible for this moment to simulate an AVD device with OpenGL ES3.2?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not fully support even GLES 3.1. Wait.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).