# I setup up the hellomap example and am getting the following errors

Tags: here-api

I am working in Android Studio and keep getting this error on run:

```
E/CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Primitive.shaderb'
[ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Default.shaderb'
[ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'spot_light_glow.rgba4.tex'
E/CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'light_flare.rgba4.tex'
A/CL_magma: [FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8730 (Thread-440)
```

I changed the emulator and it worked—but still getting the errors.
I am unsure of how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume these are just warnings (and not really errors) from the HERE Rendering Engine and they are not visible when building for release flavor. Nor they should have any impact on the app.

Answer (score 3):

Viewing the logcat output, I found the full (native) crash dump:

```
07-27 16:53:17.294  2488  2993 I magma-graphics-opengl: [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Vendor string: Google (Intel Open Source Technology Center)
07-27 16:53:17.294  2488  2993 I magma-graphics-opengl: [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Renderer string: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT3) )
07-27 16:53:17.294  2488  2993 I magma-graphics-opengl: [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - OpenGL ES 2.0
07-27 16:53:17.295  2488  2993 I magma-graphics-opengl: [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
07-27 16:53:17.297  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.297  2488  2993 I magma-graphics-opengl: [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Parsed OpenGL GPU info string - VendorId=Unknown ModelFamily= ModelCode=0
07-27 16:53:17.308  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.314  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.314  2488  2993 E CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Couldn't get context config: no error
07-27 16:53:17.314  2488  2993 I CL_magma: [INFO ] CL_magma - Failed to set rendering parameters with anti-aliasing. Will retry without anti-aliasing.
07-27 16:53:17.315  2879  2879 D PhenotypeManager: Registered: Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}
07-27 16:53:17.317  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.317  2488  2993 D EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x80c17f00: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-27 16:53:17.317  2488  2993 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x80c17f00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x80e7c380)
07-27 16:53:17.319  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 E CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Primitive.shaderb'
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 E CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Default.shaderb'
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 E CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'spot_light_glow.rgba4.tex'
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 E CL_magma: [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'light_flare.rgba4.tex'
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 F CL_magma: [FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.
--------- beginning of crash
07-27 16:53:17.325  2488  2993 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2993 (Thread-45), pid 2488 (om.here.routing)
07-27 16:53:17.334  2126  2985 I Icing   : IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.apps.messaging componentName=null serviceId=36
07-27 16:53:17.336  2126  3016 I Icing   : IndexChimeraService.getServiceInterface callingPackage=com.google.android.gms componentName=null serviceId=36
07-27 16:53:17.337  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.343  2131  2271 W MediaScanner: Error opening directory '/oem/media/', skipping: No such file or directory.
07-27 16:53:17.347  2967  2967 E ConfigUpdater: ignoring update request
07-27 16:53:17.348  1980  1980 I AlarmClock: AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
07-27 16:53:17.299  2488  2488 W Thread-45: type=1400 audit(0.0:9): avc: denied { read } for name="uptime" dev="proc" ino=4026531999 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
07-27 16:53:17.351  2049  2049 I Dialer  : VvmOmtpService - onBoot
07-27 16:53:17.358  3021  3021 I crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
07-27 16:53:17.359  1527  1527 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 2488
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 I crash_dump32: performing dump of process 2488 (target tid = 2993)
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.007/4586646:user/release-keys'
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
07-27 16:53:17.359  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : pid: 2488, tid: 2993, name: Thread-45  >>> com.here.routing <<<
07-27 16:53:17.360  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
07-27 16:53:17.361  3021  3021 F DEBUG   : Abort message: '[FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.'
07-27 16:53:17.361  3021  3021 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 000009b8  ecx 00000bb1  edx 00000006
07-27 16:53:17.362  3021  3021 F DEBUG   :     esi 0000001e  edi 000009b8
07-27 16:53:17.362  3021  3021 F DEBUG   :     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
07-27 16:53:17.362  3021  3021 F DEBUG   :     eip a9bf3ac4  ebp 83146205  esp 80afa238  flags 00000286
```

Inspecting the HERE .aar, I found that there were no GLES 2.0 shaders present at all, so I proceeded under the assumption I would need to get the Android Virtual Device to run under GLES 3.0 mode for the HERE SDK to work.

I'm on an Intel NUC that I know supports OpenGL ES 3.2, so didn't make sense that the AVD wasn't using 3.0.

Apparently, you need to forcibly enable OpenGL ES 3.2 for some graphics cards, per [the answer from this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117381/798224)

```
echo "GLESDynamicVersion = on" >> ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini
```

I restarted Android Studio and the AVD (which cold booted, indicating it noticed the configuration change) and the crash went away.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same Issue. According to Here documentation:

> The app crashes and in the logs I see "CL_magma - Couldn't load the
> default shader.": Your device must support OpenGL ES 3.0. If you are
> running a simulator, edit your emulator settings via Settings ->
> Advanced -> OpenGL ES API level. If it is set to "Autoselect", try to
> change it to "Renderer Maximum". This happens mostly on Windows
> machines.

It fixed the issue for me, using Nexus 6P

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it the following way:

**In the emulator, go to advanced [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHtDN.png) and choose "[Renderer Maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQgub.png)"**

System details:

```
Windows 10 
Android Studio 2021.2.1
```

Issue from Logcat:

```
A/CL_magma: [FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)
```