# Here sdk flutter. The map is not displayed

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremap-navigation

I am currently developing an android application based on flutter. I have integrated HERE-SDK-FLUTTER for navigation. When I run the application on my emulator I have no problem, but when I run it on my physical phone (Android 10), the map does not launch and I have this error
"'[FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.'", The application shuts down on its own.
I tried to install the sample app offered by HERE and I got the same error when launching the app.
Need your help please.

Comment: Hi, Can you please share the crash logs here meanwhile you can check this post for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878790/i-setup-up-the-hellomap-example-and-am-getting-the-following-errors

Comment: Also please have a look into this troubleshooting guide https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-lite/4.7.0.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your Android device is not supported. Check the [supported devices](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/about.html#supported-devices) page. Probably your device is older than 2015 - as most newer devices meet these requirements.

Your device must support OpenGL ES 3.0. In case this happens also on a simulator, edit your emulator settings via Settings -> Advanced -> OpenGL ES API level. If it is set to "Autoselect", try to change it to "Renderer Maximum".