# Forcefully, but gracefully, shut down incompatible Android app

Tags: process, google-play, android-lifecycle

My app requires OpenGL-ES3, and [states this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#glEsVersion) in the Manifest.

Yet, somehow, it frequently gets launched on ES2 devices, judging from the crash logs. I don't understand how the user managed to install it on an incompatible device, but here we are.

I want to add detection for ES2-only devices. Once detected, I need the app to warn the customer and then completely shut down.

There does not seem to be a proper manner in which an android app (its process) is ended. Android will just keep it alive, even if you call something like finish().

How can I force a REAL exit of an incompatible app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the openGL ES version take a look at: [Is there a way to check if Android device supports openGL ES 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198293/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-device-supports-opengl-es-2-0)

To exit from the app, have you try this?:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```